# Cloning private Channels with the Teams Graph API doesn't work

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm using the
`POST /teams/{id}/clone`

- apps - Copies Microsoft Teams apps that are installed in the team.
- channels – Copies the channel structure (but not the messages in the
  channel).
- members – Copies the members and owners of the group.
- settings – Copies all settings within the team, along with key group
  settings.
- tabs – Copies the tabs within channels.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-clone?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

The problem I face is following:

After the Post the copied Team looks like this:
[image]

The "Test Channel Private" can't be found in the new Team.

Comment: We are able to repro this issue and we have raised a bug for it.

We will let you know once we get updates on it.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. The clone operation (both from the Teams UI and from Graph API) does not support cloning of private channels.